# How to apply regex pattern on a dataframe in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe: yearDF which I get from reading an RDBMS table as below:

```
val yearDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", connectionUrl)
                                                   .option("dbtable", s"(${query}) as year2017")
                                                   .option("user", devUserName)
                                                   .option("password", devPassword)
                                                   .option("numPartitions",15)
                                                   .load()
```

In our project, my architect said that we need to apply a REGEX pattern to any data read from RDBMS table before it is persisted/loaded into the Hive table on HDFS. This is the regex pattern that I have to use:

```
"regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(%s, E'[\\\\n]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\r]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\t]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\cA]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\ca]+', ' ', 'g' ) as %s"
```

Could anyone let me know how can I apply the above regex pattern on all the columns in the dataframe: `yearDF` to form a new dataframe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yearDF.columns` will return a `Array[String]` with all the columns from `yearDF`

`map` over it to get the string expression. Use String function `.format` to replace specifier `%s` with the column name.

```
val regexExpr = yearDF.columns.map(c => "regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(%s, E'[\\\\n]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\r]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\t]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\cA]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\ca]+', ' ', 'g' ) as %s".format(c ,c))
```

Pass the generated expression to `selectExpr`:

```
yearDF.selectExpr(regexExpr : _*)
```

Comment: How different is $c to %s in this case ?

Comment: Not much. I thought you were creating the expression manually. If you want to use `%s` you need to use `.format`. I have edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: ah, okay. I am not creating it manually. This is already used in other code and was told to use the same for data ingestion. I'll try this now and get back.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. After it is changed to %s, getting the below exception:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
    Literals of type 'E' are currently not supported.(line 1, pos 88)
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(forecast_id, E'[\\n]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\r]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\t]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\cA]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\ca]+', ' ', 'g' ) as forecast_i
    at at com.partition.source.YearPartition$.main(YearPartition.scala:93)
    at com.partition.source.YearPartition.main(YearPartition.scala)

Comment: That looks like an issue with the regex. The column name `forecast_id` seems to have substituted fine.